# How to add a step to execute shell command before pre-compiled header in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, precompile

My **Xcode** project has a pre-compiled header dependencies, but this `.pch` file depends on another header file which won't be there when compile my project.

So, how to add a step to execute a shell command before pre-compiled header in **Xcode** to generate the dependent header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this, in pre-build actions you can add whatever you need to the shell script.

[image]

Comment: Yes, awesome answer! Thanks!

Comment: But, how to add a relative path here?

Comment: More info can be found here https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.3/#/itcaec37c2a6

usage: `"${SRCROOT}/path/to/my/folder/bash.sh"`